# Programmatically opening the settings app (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it currently possible to go to Apple's Settings application from a third party iPhone application? It's currently possible to open mail, safari, etc. What about Settings?

Comment: This appears to be possible before iOS 5. Twitter's app does this when airplane mode is enabled at the moment you open the app. Does anybody know how this is being accomplished?

Answer (score 16):

As of iOS 5.0 you are able to open the settings app using the `"prefs://"` URL scheme.  You are out of luck on earlier versions.

Comment: It looks like this functionality was removed in iOS 5.1, it will only work in 5.0.x

Comment: You can do it again starting with iOS 8+, see the answer from @Yatheesha below.

Answer (score 3):

suggestion from Yatheesha is right, but fails under Xcode 7.0/ swift 2.

use:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so.  It would be a welcomed addition, you should file a request for it.  There are url schemes for mail,sms etc, but not for settings.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to do this with the current version of the API sorry.

That said, you can certainly interact with the settings for your particular application.  In theory, if you had to, you could re-create the same visual experience of the Settings Application.

Comment: They specifically tell you not to do that.