# WiFi connection from iPad to Sony WiFi camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, sony-camera-api

I am planning to use Sony Lens Style camera (Wifi camera) for my iPad app, which is already released. In that app I use iPad built-in camera to get still picture. My idea is that I would like to select/switch iPad built-in camera or the WiFi camera while I use my app.

I think I need to use Sony Camera Remote API beta SDK in order to control the WiFi camera. I checked the web site and learned that WiFi setting of iPad is required to connect between iPad and the WiFi camera. Inputting SSID is also required. It seems the WiFi camera behaves like WiFi router unlike live camera.

My question is whether or not I can access (discover and connect) the WiFi camera without going back and forth between my app and setting of iPad. I mean, I would like to access (discover and connect) the WiFi camera directly from my app while I am using my app.

Is it possible?

If yes, how?

If not, it is no meaning for me to purchase the WiFi camera.

Please advise me.

Comment: All the answers I've seen on SO suggest that it is not possible without jailbreaking, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989535/ios-wifi-network-switching

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. OK, that is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mobile configuration settings to provide Wi-Fi details (SSID, key...) to iOS (confirmation by the user required).

However that just helps with the initial setup (especially for long or complex SSIDs or keys), that doesn't enable you to switch from one network to another programmatically.