# Location Services and Settings prior to iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, location, settings

I have a quick question is there a system call I can make that will provide an alert with the option to go to settings in case location services have been disabled on iOS versions prior to 5?

As far as I know there is no URL scheme for the settings app before 5.0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. There is no URL scheme for that.

You can refer these threads :

[UIAlertView like "Turn On Location Services to allow maps to determine your location". Settings + Cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784654/uialertview-like-turn-on-location-services-to-allow-maps-to-determine-your-loca)

[Programmatically opening the settings app (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736047/programmatically-opening-the-settings-app-iphone)

[is it possible to open Settings App using openURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090373/is-it-possible-to-open-settings-app-using-openurl)

Also, you can check your CLLocationManagerDelegate didFailWithError method for error code. If the error code is kCLErrorDenied, you know that Location services are not enabled