# iOS UIAlertView button to go to Setting App

Tags: ios, uialertview, settings.bundle

Is there a way to have the button of a UIAlertView go to the Settings App for the specific App calling it?

Thanks

Answer (score 87, accepted):

For example:

```
NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

And

```
[font=]
About — prefs:root=General&path=About
Accessibility — prefs:root=General&path=ACCESSIBILITY
Airplane Mode On — prefs:root=AIRPLANE_MODE
Auto-Lock — prefs:root=General&path=AUTOLOCK
Brightness — prefs:root=Brightness
Bluetooth — prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth
Date & Time — prefs:root=General&path=DATE_AND_TIME
FaceTime — prefs:root=FACETIME
General — prefs:root=General
Keyboard — prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard
iCloud — prefs:root=CASTLE
iCloud Storage & Backup — prefs:root=CASTLE&path=STORAGE_AND_BACKUP
International — prefs:root=General&path=INTERNATIONAL
Location Services — prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES
Music — prefs:root=MUSIC
Music Equalizer — prefs:root=MUSIC&path=EQ
Music Volume Limit — prefs:root=MUSIC&path=VolumeLimit
Network — prefs:root=General&path=Network
Nike + iPod — prefs:root=NIKE_PLUS_IPOD
Notes — prefs:root=NOTES
Notification — prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID
Phone — prefs:root=Phone
Photos — prefs:root=Photos
Profile — prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList
Reset — prefs:root=General&path=Reset
Safari — prefs:root=Safari
Siri — prefs:root=General&path=Assistant
Sounds — prefs:root=Sounds
Software Update — prefs:root=General&path=SOFTWARE_UPDATE_LINK
Store — prefs:root=STORE
Twitter — prefs:root=TWITTER
Usage — prefs:root=General&path=USAGE
VPN — prefs:root=General&path=Network/VPN
Wallpaper — prefs:root=Wallpaper
Wi-Fi — prefs:root=WIFI`
prefs:root=INTERNET_TETHERING
```

Comment: I was testing this and realized it only worked on ios 5. I was testing it on an iPhone 3G, not S. I know its old lol.  Is there a way for iOS 4? Or is it limited to devices that support multitasking with iOS 5?

Comment: Yes, It works in ios6 & ios7 if you add a new item whoes value is 'prefs' in URL Types. I have tested it in ios7.

Answer (score 27):

**Opening settings apps programmatically is possible only from iOS 8. So, use the following code...**

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]&&
   [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
{
  //...Location service is enabled
}
else
{
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]<8.0)
    {
    UIAlertView* curr1=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"This app does not have access to Location service" message:@"You can enable access in Settings->Privacy->Location->Location Services" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [curr1 show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView* curr2=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"This app does not have access to Location service" message:@"You can enable access in Settings->Privacy->Location->Location Services" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Settings", nil];
        curr2.tag=121;
        [curr2 show];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
 NSLog(@"buttonIndex:%d",buttonIndex);

   if (alertView.tag == 121 && buttonIndex == 1)
 {
  //code for opening settings app in iOS 8
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
 }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to go to the General Top Level of Settings App, not your App's Setting options?

Comment: No @zonabi, iOS SDK didn't provided any option for that.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, this does not work in iOS 5.1 whatsoever. I have been fighting it all morning, and then ran across this blog

http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2011/11/04/settings-urls/

Answer (score 6):

In ios5 and above...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General"]];
```

Comment: would apple approve this way of opening settings app?

Comment: Works ok - but you need to set your url types to open prefs : http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq6qQ.png

Answer (score 1):

It works on iOS8+ also,but we need to change something

```
NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```