# Accessing Settings app values and opening it if needed

Tags: ios, settings, uialertview, settings.bundle

I have seen that there are known apps, such as Twitter and Facebook, that display a "*Turn Off Airplane Mode or Use Wi-Fi to Access Data*" message within an alert view, with a button that switches to the Settings app, when no network is detected as the app goes foreground. This message is the same in all apps where I saw it, is this alert view a kind of predefined one that you can use? Similar to the one displayed when checking `locationServicesEnabled`...

I found some posts dealing with this issue some time ago, for example:
[iOS UIAlertView button to go to Setting App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092142/ios-uialertview-button-to-go-to-setting-app), and it seems (or seemed) to be a way to read the values in the iOS' Settings app, but I couldn't find any of this in the Apple Developer's documentation... is there any public API for accessing those values? Would an app be rejected if accessing them as in the post I linked?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Till iOS 5.0, you can use the URL scheme to open the Settings App from third-party apps using the URLScheme like:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];
```

Unfortunately, iOS 5.1 and iOS 6 not supports this feature.

You can use the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) for checking the Wi-Fi state.

For displaying the default alertview when the Wi-fi is off or in AirPlane mode you can use the **Application uses Wi-Fi** flag in the info.plist

Refer [InfoPlistKeyReference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) for details:

> **UIRequiresPersistentWiFi**
>
> *“Application uses Wi-Fi”*
>
> Specifies whether this app requires a Wi-Fi connection.

Comment: Thanks! So, there is no way to access the rest of the Settings fields in iOS 5+?

Comment: @AppsDev: For checking the location service, etc. It can be done via code. But you can't open the settings app, or change the value by code