# How to navigate to 'General/Accessibility/Hearing Aids" page directly from the App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

It is possible to navigate to the device settings directly from the App for iOS versions greater than 8.

This is the link I referred to: 
[iOS UIAlertView button to go to Setting App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092142/ios-uialertview-button-to-go-to-setting-app)

This allows only 2 levels of navigation: root and path.
Example: General/Accessibility

Is there a way to access 3 levels of navigation to reach the hearing aids page of device settings?
ie: General/Accessibility/Hearing Aids

Any help in objective-c or xamarin.ios will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I think it won't allow to go on third level so better to go manually