# Custom view to allow location services

Tags: objective-c, location-services

I want to be able to create my own view to allow location services from my iOS app. I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784654/uialertview-like-turn-on-location-services-to-allow-maps-to-determine-your-loca) that it's possible to customise the description of the default iOS location services alert, but what I want is making my own view.

Is this possible?
Thanks!

Comment: I doubt it. The entire point of the approval view is that you have no control over it, and therefore cannot manipulate or bypass it to fool the user or bypass their consent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. All you can/should do is popping it at the right time. You should make sure that user is informed that permission is really needed, according to several researches (yes, citation needed :) ).

**EDIT:**  it pops up when you first call start monitoring/updating location method from your `CLLocationManager` instance.
Since iOS8, you should call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` or `requestAlwaysAuthorization` for it to pop up.
[Here](http://techcrunch.com/2014/04/04/the-right-way-to-ask-users-for-ios-permissions/) you can find some very good ideas about it.

Comment: How can I pop it at the right time? For example after pressing one button of my custom view?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can not change the Apple Services Authorisations;

I would recommend you to create your custom view with "allow" & "dont allow" buttons. And than on "allow" pressed request apple permission witch will prompt the iOS or mac OS alert.

Though it seems not user-friendly. Apple users are used to this. Nobody will mind, and you will still show your own design. A lot of famous apps do that.

Comment: That would be a good idea. So, how can I prompt the iOS location services alert whenever I want?

Comment: yes, you simply ask for location update, and if its a first time it will ask him. You should consider that this is managed through iOS Settings.