# Want to enable location services through xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new in ios and I want to know how can I enable location services through programming when I'm using this below....

[image]

As I'm using this label to show Whenever location service is disabled And an enable button(Green) to enable location services.But how to this programmatically.How will I get to know Location services are disabled and how the button will enable this.Please help me out.

Comment: Please read the rule before asking questions

Comment: Zoho,can You refer me the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **CLLocationManager's locationServicesEnabled** property to check the system-wide/overall availability. Use your **CLLocationManagerDelegate's locationManager: didFailWithError:** method and check for a **kCLErrorDenied** error to see if the user denied location services.

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){

           NSLog(@"Location Services Enabled");

           if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied){
                 [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Permission Denied" 
                                                        message:@"To re-enable, please go to Settings and turn on Location Service for this app." 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil]show];

            }
        }
```

**Choice-2**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```

> if location service disable for your app then its give you error
>
> Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 1.)"

**Update**

if user denied the permission, we cant enable in programmatically, user can manually enable the location services, for more [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784654/uialertview-like-turn-on-location-services-to-allow-maps-to-determine-your-loca)

Comment: Can I also USe if (kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted) { UIAlertView}; This also for parential control Right?